# Timers In Network Protocols

Tags: c, linux, timer, network-programming

I'm building a network application in RedHat/C with a protocol called SMPP that is being used in telecom to send SMS.

I'm at a point where I send messages (~70 SMS/second) to the server and I have to wait to a few seconds and for a successful response and delete the messages, but if the message timed-out then I have to resend the message to the server.

The question is how to design something to retry the expired messages?

Comment: 70!  Are you spamming the server?

Comment: no :), this is the max number of SMS I can send. we use this service to send to the subscribers that their phone monthly bill is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an id in the SMPP spec called sequence_number - this should be monotonically incrementing for every request you make and the response coming back from the server will have the sequence_number of the request it is responding to.

If you wait for a bit (maybe 10 seconds, maybe longer) and you don't get your response back you can re-send the request with the same sequence_number and the server should spot it as a duplicate if it did receive it first time; if it did not receive it first time then it will treat it as a new request.

The server may also make requests to your client; e.g. here is a delivery receipt or here is a mobile-originate message - it will also have it's own sequence_number counter and you should acknowledge it's requests with responses having the same sequence number. You should track the sequence numbers you have seen so you can tell if you hit a duplicate request.

This property is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence and is something you should become familiar with if you are implementing telecoms protocols.

In order to get your 70 msgs/sec you will likely need to build on top of  Idempotence using a sliding window http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_(data)#Sliding_Window so you can have a maximum of N (maybe 10) requests outstanding you are still waiting for the response acknowledgements to - unless you are very close to the SMPP server with very low latency.

Doing SMPP right is not trivial I would recommend you read SMPP v3.4 spec front to back before you get too far into an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are asking for so the answer will be also probably not very precise.

I would suggest to see how this is implemented in some existing solutions. I have worked a bit with [kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) and mbuni (this is rather for MMS) and I suggest take a look at kannel especially.

Kannel is basically open source SMS gateway and have working SMPP support.

Take also a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799187/kannel-as-smpp-server) stackoverflow thread which may also help to understand some ideas.

Comment: sorry about that, so the question is how to design something to retry the expired messages